# Fixed columns in bootstrap 3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am curious to how this is achieve this concept, I was talking to a friend and they stated all I have to do is add two floating divs for the sidebars (3 column layout), change the width of the container and then the columns inside will arrange and resize and needed.

What I currently have is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"> Side Bar one </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"> Content </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> Side Bar Two </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I assumed that `col-md-2`, because it has a float on it, is already "fixed width". But apparently not. So how could I implement this "fixed width" concept and still have the responsiveness?

Comment: Well obvi I couldnt use it with a row, col based layout, I would have to change it up

Comment: Apologies, I need another Coffee :) Although, surely the fixed width would be.. `container` without the `-fluid`? Added a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw7rK/12/ and for [Full Screen Result](http://jsfiddle.net/Mw7rK/12/embedded/result/)